Is there anyway to filter key in dict to match parameter of function when pass **dict into function?
Hiii,
I face a situation like this: I want to write a general wrapper class:
...

def do_thing(self,
                source_ids,
                src_len,
                len_src_oovs,
                extended_source_ids,
                sos_token_id,
                unk_token_id,
                max_len=None,
                dec_inp_ids=None):
    
...




        for batch in e:
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            source_ids = batch['source_ids']
            extended_source_ids = batch['extended_source_ids']
            list_src_oovs = batch['source_oovs']
            src_len = batch['src_len']
            len_src_oovs = batch['len_src_oovs']
            dec_inp_ids = batch['dec_inp_ids']
            target_ids = batch['target_ids']

            target_texts = batch['target_text']
            batch_size = len(source_ids)

            preds, coverages, atts, cov_losses = model.do_thing(**batch)


As the batch has some redundant keys in calling model(..) it raises an error got an unexpected keyword argument
Is there anyway to filter it, but I don't actually need to know which parameters that function needs?  Just knowing that, all the needed things are in the batch.

Your question makes literally no sense. Where is the function, let alone a class?

it literally has sense and doesn't need to show a class :) . But I updated a function demo tho.

It doesn't make sense ;) Thankkkk youuuuuuuuuuu

@roganjosh This sentence alone makes it clear what the question is: "As the batch has some redundant keys in calling model(..) it raises an error got an unexpected keyword argument".

:) I think **kwargs will help in my case. I did think about it before post this, but I hoped there's another way. But thank you for taking a look :)

@tjns Did you try the solution in this answer in the linked question?

@blhsing no it doesn't. Where is the class? There wasn't even a function when it was asked

@blhsing Thank you. I just noticed it now. It seems work

@roganjosh stop it -.-
